# centos Shell script to mv dynamic file names

Tags: linux, centos, mv

I have the following file structure:

`/uploads/<blog_id>/10/155`

For every blog_id there is a folder named `10` and inside that folder is another folder `155`.  folder `155` has a bunch of files in it.

I am simply trying to move all files from `/10/155` to simply `/10` for all `blog_id`s.

Basically, I just want to eliminate the `155` folder, moving its contents down into `10`.  I don't care if `155` stays there or is deleted.

I have tried several versions of this script:

```
for file in /var/www/html/uploads/*/10/155; do mv $file ${file%/*}/10; done
```

Ultimately, I was able to rename the 155 folder to 10 like: `*/10/10`.  I moved 155 down 2 levels (next to `10`) like: `*/155`.

Any help?

Comment: In general, if you want to move `$path` up one level, you can do `mv "$path" "${path%/*}/.."`

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the blog_id directories.  Then for each of those you can do what you need:

```
for blog_dir in /uploads/*; do
    mv "$blog_dir"/10/155/* "$blog_dir"/10/
    rmdir "$blog_dir"/10/155
done
```